# Full Calendar wont show events taken from AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I need to get some events from a DB using AJAX and show them in my Full Calendar. The problem is my JSON feed doesn't have `start` and `end` but has all the dates seperated by a `,` (eg: 15-06-2020,16-06-2020) I was hoping to use `.split(',')` and set the values from there but couldnt get it to work. This is what I tried

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    plugins: ['dayGrid'],
    editable: true,
    firstDay: 1,
    eventLimit: true,
    events: function(start, end, callback) {

      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:8092/api/leavecal/getleavesbyemp/200027502420",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {

          var eventsList = [];
          var count = 0;
          while (count < data.length) {

            var dateArray = data[count].date.split(',');
            var startDate = dateArray[0];
            var endDate = dateArray[dateArray.length - 1];

            eventsList.push({
              start: startDate,
              end: endDate
            });

            console.log(startDate + " " + endDate);
            count++

          }
          callback(eventsList);

        }
      });

    }

  });

  calendar.render();
});
```

```html
<div id="calendar"></div>
```

I'm not sure where to go from here

Comment: You'll need to supply your dates in a supported format which doesn't have any room for ambiguity. e.g. yyyy-mm-dd is better because a) it's supported by JS Date / fullCalendar (see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-parsing), and b) it can't be confused between dd-mm-yyyy and mm-dd-yyyy. While you're at it, why not change your API so it outputs the dates in separate fields as well?

Comment: Also `events: function(start, end, callback) {` is incorrect - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function. (I assume you took an example from v3 code without realising. v4 has different syntax). And you should really be sending the supplied start and end dates to your server so it can restrict the results it returns to only those actually required in the calendar right now - otherwise, if you have a lot of historical events (once your app has been live for a while), you'll end up pointlessly downloading a lot of data, 90% of which won't ever be viewed.

Comment: @ADyson i changed the dates to yyy-mm-dd format, and thanks for that tip. I have accidentally used the v3 function as you mentioned. I tried to do the v4 format given in the site but im a bit confused now. should i use that same format for ajax, or can i use the `"GET"` method i used?

Comment: also as for the api, unfortunately its a bit too complex for me to change and my colleagues asked me to leave it as it is for some reason

Comment: here you have a working Pen: https://codepen.io/balexandre/pen/NWxRGGd?editors=0010

Comment: "should i use that same format for ajax"...yes, that's not relevant to the change of function syntax. Your main problem is that `callback()` will not send the events back to fullCalendar, because it's the wrong input argument from the function. The answer below should help you, anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assumptions:

- as the question does not specify the version, I'll assume the latest stable version, 4.4
- I will also provide the array of dates instead

in order to all work, you will need to change the date format unless you [change the locale](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/locale)

if you get dates as a string `15-06-2020,16-06-2020`, just create a simple array from it and use the code bellow

```js
function convertToObjects(str) {
    // str = "15-06-2020,16-06-2020"
    return str.split(',').map(function(elm) { return { date: elm }; })
}
```

**the events signature** is not correct in your code, it should be, as @ADyson pointed out [the docs show](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function) as `(info, successCallback, failureCallback)` where you pass the array of events into the `successCallback([])` or any error into the `failureCallback(new Error('Not good!'))` and `info` is where you can get the requested data range.

```js
function getAllEvents(info, successCallback, failureCallback) {
  const data = [
    { date: '15-06-2020' },
    { date: '16-06-2020' }
  ];
  // const data = convertToObjects(<your string of dates>);
  successCallback(processData(data));
}

function processData (arr) {
  // [{date;'15-06-2020'},{date:'16-06-2020'}]
  const eventsList = [];

  arr.forEach(function(entry, i) {
    // 15-06-2020 -> 2020-06-15
    const dt = entry.date;
    const formattedDate = `${dt.substr(6,4)}-${dt.substr(3,2)}-${dt.substr(0,2)}`;
    eventsList.push({
      id: `evt-${i+1}`,
      start: formattedDate,
      end: formattedDate,
      title: `Event #${i+1}`
    });
  });

  return eventsList;
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  const calendarEl = document.getElementById("calendar");
  const calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    plugins: ['dayGrid'],
    editable: true,
    firstDay: 1,
    eventLimit: true,
    events: getAllEvents,
  });

  calendar.render();
});
```

```html
<!-- CSS -->
<link href="https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/daygrid@4.4.0/main.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/core@4.4.0/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- JS -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/core@4.4.0/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/daygrid@4.4.0/main.js"></script>


<div id="calendar"></div>
```

Answer created from drafting it first on https://codepen.io/balexandre/pen/NWxRGGd?editors=1010

Comment: thanks a lot for this! i'll change the format to yyyy-mm-dd as well. connected this to my api but currently only the last item is being shown but i can find a workaround for it. thanks again!

Comment: add `debugger` to a line in code and that will stop the execution and enter in debug mode, so you can add more breakpoints and go line by line checking the variables and what's going on... remember that each event should have an `id` so they can be treated differently